# Pheanstalk does not preform job

Tags: php, symfony, beanstalkd

I am using Symfony framework 3 with LeezyPheanstalkBundle. This is my first time using Pheanstalk. I would like to create event that fire up on creating new power plant. I created subscriber, job manager, job class. The code works. I can see the data is send to tube, and than job delete itself like i set to do in subscriber. I dont undestand why nothing happens after that. in this line of code i tell what command i want to set:

$this->jobManager->createJob("power_plant:create",$payload);

if i try testing the code with cache:clear or doctrine:generate:entity and it do nothing. So my question is where I declare what command I would like to run and if I must create command too or I can use service or class witch I would like to run when my event is fired up? I already created my custom class that have parameter power plant name and than create some extra tables for that new power plant. I would like to do this using pheanstalk, but here is my problem, that I dont know why this commands do not runs like I would expected. And also documentation for this is very poor.

Evet Subscriber:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\EventListener;

use AppBundle\Event\PowerPlantEvent;
use AppBundle\Manager\ManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use AppBundle\Event\Events;

class PowerPlantSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
protected $jobManager;

public function __construct(ManagerInterface $jobManager)
{
    $this->jobManager = $jobManager;
}

public static function getSubscribedEvents()
{
    return [
        Events::POWERPLANT_CREATE => ['onPowerPlantCreate', 0],
        Events::POWERPLANT_DELETE => ['onPowerPlantDelete', 0],
    ];
}

public function onPowerPlantCreate(PowerPlantEvent $event)
{
    $power_plant = $event->getPowerPlant();
    $payload = [
            "name"      => $power_plant->getName(),
            "tech_name"  => $power_plant->getTechName(),
            "system"  => $power_plant->getSystem()
    ];
    //$job = $this->jobManager->createJob("power_plant:create",$payload);
    $job = $this->jobManager->createJob('doctrine:generate:entity --entity=AppBundle:Test --format=annotation --fields="title:string(255) body:text" --no-interaction',$payload);
    $data = $this->jobManager->getData($job);
    $this->jobManager->deleteJob($job);
}

public function onPowerPlantDelete(PowerPlantEvent $event)
{
    $power_plant = $event->getPowerPlant();
    $payload = [
            "name"  => $power_plant->getName(),
            "tech_name"  => $power_plant->getTechName(),
            "system"  => $power_plant->getSystem()
    ];        
    $job = $this->jobManager->createJob("power_plant:delete",$payload);
    $data = $this->jobManager->getData($job);
    $this->jobManager->deleteJob($job);
}   
}
```

Job manager:

```
namespace AppBundle\Manager;

use Leezy\PheanstalkBundle\Proxy\PheanstalkProxy;
use AppBundle\Queue\Job;

/**
 * Job manager class
 */
abstract class JobManager implements ManagerInterface
{

/**
* @var $pheanstalk 
*/
protected $pheanstalk;

/**
* @var $name
*/
protected $name;

/**
 *@var job;
 */
protected $job;

public function __construct(PheanstalkProxy $pheanstalk, Job $job)
{
    $this->pheanstalk = $pheanstalk;
    $this->job = $job;
}

/**
* Create job using pheanstalk
*
* @var $command
* @var $payload
*/
public function createJob($command, $payload)
{
    $jobData = [
        "command" => $command,
        "meta"  => $payload
    ];

    $this->pheanstalk->useTube($this->tubeName);

    return $this->job->enqueue($command, $jobData, $this->tubeName);
}

/**
 * Get job data
 *
 * @var $job
 */
public function getData($job)
{
    return $job->getData();
}

/**
 * Delete job
 *
 * @var $job
 */
public function deleteJob($job)
{
    return $this->job->deleteJob($job);
}

/**
* Set tube name
*
* @var $name
*/
public function setTubeName($name)
{
    $this->tubeName = $name;
}

}
```

Job class:

```
namespace AppBundle\Queue;

use Leezy\PheanstalkBundle\Proxy\PheanstalkProxy;

class Job {

/**
 * @var $pheanstalk 
 */
protected $pheanstalk;

public function __construct(PheanstalkProxy $pheanstalk) {
    $this->pheanstalk = $pheanstalk;
}

/**
 * Preform job
 *
 * @var $job
 * @var array $args
 * @var string $tubeName
 * @var integer $priority
 * @var integer $delay
 * @var integer $ttr
 */
public function enqueue($job, array $args, $tubeName, $priority = 65536, $delay = 0, $ttr = 120)
{
    if (!preg_match('/[a-z0-9\.]+/i', $job)) {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException("Invalid job name");
    }

    $this->pheanstalk->put(json_encode($args), $priority, $delay, $ttr);

    return $this->pheanstalk->watch($tubeName)->ignore('default')->reserve();
}

/**
 * Delete job
 *
 * @var $job
 */
public function deleteJob($job)
{
    $this->pheanstalk->delete($job);
}

}
```

Comment: You don't have the separate job running that will actually reserve the job (from a watched tube), and act upon it.  At the moment, when you are queueing the job, you are also then reserving it to read it back out of the queue  but that doesn't even do anything with it.

Comment: @AlisterBulman I was reading this documentation from: https://github.com/armetiz/LeezyPheanstalkBundle . I first declare tube name and than put the payload there with createJob("power_plant:create",$payload). So far I understand. But after that I am not sure. The command power_plant:create must be created as service or I can run some custom class? And after I put the payload into tube I must do $job->getData() and than delete job? Do I need to do exec($data); to run the command or not?